# php replace paragraph to newline

Tags: php, newline, paragraph

how to replace `<p>hello</p> <p>world</p>` to `hello<br />world <br />`

I've tried searching on stack but there is no matched result.

Comment: no matched result? just google replace string php. no attempts whatsoever?

Comment: @Ghost **DO NOT** use regex and string replacement to work with HTML

Comment: @AleksG fine. then use an HTML parser

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: in fact I want strip html tag from string and still keep new line including br and p tags, then replace br with \n, but I cannot replace p tag with \n

Comment: @user3792270 if your requirements are different to those in your question, edit your question to state the correct requirements.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this by using str_replace() function.

For instance:

```
$string = "<p>hello</p> <p>world</p>";
$string = str_replace('<p>', '', $string);
$string = str_replace('</p>', '<br />' , $string);
```

Comment: Won't work, remove the first and last <p> </p> too. breaking the owl paragraphe

Answer (score 4):

I try this myself and get what I expected

```
$pattern = '/<p>(\w+)\<\/p>/';
$subject = '<p>hello</p><p>world</p>';
$replacement = '${1}<br/>';
$out = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

I just wonder which is better regex or str_replace

I wrote a better solution, hope everybody can see it helpful and maybe improve it

```
$pattern = '/<p(.*?)>((.*?)+)\<\/p>/';
$replacement = '${2}<br/>';
$subject = 'html string';
$out = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to prevent breaking the first and last `<p></p>` :

```
$string = str_replace($string, '</p><p>', '');
```

But if a space comes between the tags, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = '<p>hello</p> <p>world</p>';
$replaceArr = array('<p>', '</p>', '</p> <p>');
$replacementArr = array('', '', '<br />');
$str = str_replace($replaceArr, $replacementArr, $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Try above code.